# How to get a value from json based on key in bash

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to extract value of a branch from the below json/test.json file using jq

```
{
    "pipeline": {
        "name": "test",
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234:role/service-role/AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-us-west-2-test",
        "artifactStore": {
            "type": "S3"
        },
        "stages": [{
            "name": "Source",
            "actions": [{
                "name": "Source",
                "actionTypeId": {
                    "category": "Source",
                    "version": "1"
                },
                "runOrder": 1,
                "configuration": {
                    "Branch": "experiment"
                }
            }]
        }],
        "version": 1
    }
}
```

Below is jq command I'm using `jq -r '.pipeline.stages.actions.configuration.Branch' test.json`which returns **jq: error (at test.json:76): Cannot index array with string "actions".** I'm I missing something here

Comment: Looks like the first key is "pipeline" but you have "pipelines" in your command.

Comment: @AndyLester I did make the modifications now it throws a different error

Comment: And what is that different error?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: @AndyLester updated the question with the new error

Comment: Should it not be `.pipeline.stages[0].actions[0].configuration.Branch`? As both `actions` and `stages` are arrays

Comment: @Dominik Thanks!! that worked

Comment: I made it an answer that you can mark as the answer @samuel ;)

Comment: @samuel Please read my answer as well, which shows you how to figure this out step-by-step, because you will run into this problem again, I guarantee it.  It's part of life with JSON and jq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json key address should be `.pipeline.stages[0].actions[0].configuration.Branch` so that would make your command look like this:

```sh
jq -r '.pipeline.stages[0].actions[0].configuration.Branch' test.json
```

That's because both `stages` and `actions` are arrays with both only a single item in them.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing queries, and something doesn't work at first, then try something simple and keep adding to it.  So in your case, start with

```
$ jq -r '.pipelines' test.json
null
```

Aha, it's "pipeline" not "pipelines", so go from there:

```
$ jq -r '.pipeline' test.json
{
  "name": "test",
  "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234:role/service-role/AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-us-west-2-test",
  "artifactStore": {
    "type": "S3"
  },
  "stages": [
    {
      "name": "Source",
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Source",
          "actionTypeId": {
            "category": "Source",
            "version": "1"
          },
          "runOrder": 1,
          "configuration": {
            "Branch": "experiment"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 1
}
```

So that works.  Now we want to get to "stages" so we do this

```
$ jq -r '.pipeline.stages' test.json
[
  {
    "name": "Source",
    "actions": [
      {
        "name": "Source",
        "actionTypeId": {
          "category": "Source",
          "version": "1"
        },
        "runOrder": 1,
        "configuration": {
          "Branch": "experiment"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Note that "stages" gives you an array, not just a hash, so you have to refer to [0], the zeroth element.

```
$ jq -r '.pipeline.stages[0]' test.json
{
  "name": "Source",
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Source",
      "actionTypeId": {
        "category": "Source",
        "version": "1"
      },
      "runOrder": 1,
      "configuration": {
        "Branch": "experiment"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now you can get to "actions"

```
$ jq -r '.pipeline.stages[0].actions' test.json
[
  {
    "name": "Source",
    "actionTypeId": {
      "category": "Source",
      "version": "1"
    },
    "runOrder": 1,
    "configuration": {
      "Branch": "experiment"
    }
  }
]
```

and then the zeroth one

```
$ jq -r '.pipeline.stages[0].actions[0]' test.json
{
  "name": "Source",
  "actionTypeId": {
    "category": "Source",
    "version": "1"
  },
  "runOrder": 1,
  "configuration": {
    "Branch": "experiment"
  }
}
```

and finally to configuration and Branch

```
$ jq -r '.pipeline.stages[0].actions[0].configuration.Branch' test.json
experiment
```